# Does Flutter support cascading grids?

Tags: layout, flutter

Does Flutter support cascading grid style layouts such as:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create 4 Expanded in a Row and add Column of Containers in each Expanded:

Below is the code I ran and gives exact result you wish:

```
new Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                        child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                    height: 50.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 24.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 150.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                    new Expanded(
                        child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                    height: 140.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 90.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 58.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                    new Expanded(
                        child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                    height: 20.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 220.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 50.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                    new Expanded(
                        child: new Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                                new Container(
                                    height: 50.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 150.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                                new Container(
                                    height: 100.0,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                ),
                            ],
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            )
```

It gives the below result:

[image]

Comment: Bad idea. This would have horrible performances with a huge data set (due to rendering everything even if off screen).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [CustomScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) or a [SliderGrid](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SliverGrid-class.html) with a custom `gridDelegate`